# Getting error while implementing firebase dependencies for FCM in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, firebase-cloud-messaging, access-token

I am working on FCM in android studio. While implementing firebase dependency I got some error. Please Solve my problem. Thank You :)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
// implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
```

Error I am getting like this

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-52:19 to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me updating the version numbers worked. Take a look here for the newest versions: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

For example:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1
```